# Spring boot: serving multi page react content

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I'm trying something very simple; create a Spring boot backend with a multi-page React frontend.

However I'm running into some issues when the static js and css files (build by React) are being served in the packaged application.

The finished build looks like this:

[image: target structure]

My React app (browse)routing is as follows:

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <>
                  <Switch>
                    <Route path="/blog" component={Blog}/>
                    <Route path="/blog/:postId" component={Blog}/>
                    <Route path="/404" component={NotFound}/>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route component={ErrorPage}/>
                  </Switch>

        </>
    );
  }
}
```

All first level paths work (`/`, `/blog`, `/404`) but whenever I add a level like `/blog/some-post` I get 404's on the static js and css files build by React.
For example:

```
GET http://localhost:8081/blog/static/css/2.something.chunk.css
```

The only relevant spring dependency I use is spring-web (there's no Thymeleaf or other templating going on)

I'm thinking it's a controller issue, so I added the following but without success

```java
@Controller
public class WebMainController {

  @RequestMapping({"/","/blog","{**}/static/{**}"})
  public String index() {
    return "index.html";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/blog/{**}")
  public String blog() {
    return "/";
  }
}
```

I tried playing with the values / wildcards / etc... but without success.
The request to the "css" file (given above) doesn't even pass the controller.

I tried several solutions I found on the web but none seem to work. Going from adding custom resource handlers to copying the build files elsewhere...

Am I missing something stupid here?
(my [complete pom](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbosman/e1bab02b53bc2675596001a1e5ce3232))

Comment: why do you have `GET http://localhost:8081/blog/static/css/2.something.chunk.css` ? it should be `http://localhost:8081/static/css/2.something.chunk.css`

Comment: It's just to show what request is being executed by the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough information to tell for sure, but I guess instead of `http://localhost:8081/blog/static/css/2.something.chunk.css` it should look up `http://localhost:8081/static/css/2.something.chunk.css`

You said that all works for one-level paths, so `<base href="/">` at the head of HTML code should solve the problem. Or use absolute paths everywhere.

Comment: This works! (in combination with the controller methods in my question)!

Answer (score 1):

When building a **Single Page App**, the backend server should return the index page for all the routes. Then the `react-router` will do the job.

The following code might solve the problem :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{path:[^.]+}")
public String index() {
  return "forward:/";
}
```

Comment: Also tried this but it results in a ServletException:
`ServletException: Circular view path [index.html]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/index.html] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.`

Comment: I edited my answer to prevent selecting static resources

Comment: Would this ```"/{path:[.]+}")```  work, as it looks the '^' and '\\' seems unnecessary? And could you explain what returning "forward:/" does.

Comment: it simply forward the request to the `/` endpoint (the index endpoint). The url isn't modified so react router can display the appropriate route.